# How to switch anchor links between a local and web address/alternate addresses?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, alternate

I don't know if this is unique to me or not, but unable to find anywhere else.

Sometimes I download a set of webpages or a site (HTTrack) and build custom access pages for them for myself and others (like RPG references for my own quick refernce).

What I would like to do is to have the reference page switch addresses between the local and network address depending on availability and access:

If the first address is available (local one) - use it, but if not and online - use the web address, otherwise inform the user of the sad news:

```
        web page: equipment_index.html
        local address: ./Equipmentac5b.html
        web address: domain/Equipment.aspx?Id=438
```

You view equipment_index.html locally, all is fine, pulls up Equipmentac5b.html from local directory.
You give equipment_index.html to a friend, loads page, can't find Equipmentac5b.html, so it loads the page from alternate/web address domain/Equipment.aspx?Id=438 (providing the friend is online).

Thinking about adding two properties to <a> tag "data-network" and "data-local", href is empty, and an onclick() function that uses window.location.assign() for page navigation.

```
        javascript:
        function pageJump(id){
            anchor = document.getElementById(id);
            try {
                window.location.assign(anchor.dataset.local);
            }
            catch(err){
                try {
                    window.location.assign(anchor.dataset.network);
                }
                catch(err){
                    alert("Unable to find desired page.");
                }
            }
        }

        html, for each needed link:
        &lt;a id="link001" href="" data-local="local_address" data-network="web_address" onclick="pageJump(this.id);"&gt;some name&lt;/a&gt;
```

I know it is mentioned (many, many, many .... times) that adding your own attributes to a tag will invalidate your HTML document and may break it (and just as many times that it is ok), so, is there an easier/better way (in pure javascript) or html to specify an alternate loading address for links?

Some may wonder why not just give all the files with the reference document?  For various reasons it may not be feasible to pass along the secondary files.

Comment: In modern browsers adding data to html is done by using [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) which can then be accessed via the `dataset` property of the dom object, eg `<a data-network="" data-local="">`, `console.log(element.dataset['network'])`

Answer (score 0):

Well, searched far and wide for various reasons my code wasn't working. Found the missing info and this now works.

```
      javascript:
      function pageJump(id){
        var anchor = id;
        try {
          //alert(anchor.dataset.local);  //for testing, display address 
          window.location.href = anchor.dataset.local;
          return false;
        }
        catch(err){
          try {
            //alert(anchor.dataset.network);  //for testing, display address
            window.location.href = anchor.dataset.network;
            return false;
          }
          catch(err){
            alert("Unable to find desired page.");
          }
        }
      }

      html, change address/files for each link set:
      <a href="" data-local="file:///drive:/path/default1.html" data-network="http://domain/path/alternate1.html" onclick="return pageJump(this);">some text</a>
```

This final piece was the return in "return pageJump(this);".  If you don't have the 'return', in my experience, it just reloads the page.

I left my test points (the alerts) in, just commented them out.